# Как получить ссылку страницы категории wordpress на которой нахожусь?

Tags: php, wordpress, переменные, woocommerce, link

Есть интернет-магазин на wordpress+woocommerce. Вопрос: как получить ссылку на страницу категории товара на которой нахожусь. Да, вот такое обращение напрямую сработает

```
echo get_term_link( 3577 ,'product_cat');
```

но мне нужно заменить конкретный `id=3577` на переменную, которая будет получать `id` конкретной категории. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1  get_query_var( 'cat' )

Вариант 2 get_queried_object()->term_id; не проверял

Comment: спасибо за наводку на функцию, но вы не учли, что категория продуктов это таксономия, поэтому окончательный ответ ниже

Answer (score 0):

```
$taxonomy_name = get_query_var('taxonomy'); //Название самой таксономии
$itemcat = get_query_var('term'); //Ярлык текущего элемента таксономии
echo get_term_link( $itemcat ,'product_cat'); //ссылка на таксономию
```